# Approximation of Lipschitz function in uniform norm

Tags: real-analysis, approximation, alternative-proof, lipschitz-functions

Let $F =\left\{ f\in C^1[a,b] : || f|| \leq c, ||f'||\leq k\right\}$ and

$G = \left\{f\in C[a,b] : || f|| \leq c, f \text{ is globally Lipschitz with Lipschitz constant }\leq k \right\}$

where $a,b,c,k$ are fixed real constants, and the norm is the "sup" norm.

Then, the claim is that the closure of $F$ in $C([a,b])$,  $\overline F$, is $G$.

I was able to show that $\overline F \subset G$, but I have no idea how to show the converse. I think that the same question was already asked(
[Every $K$-Lipschitz function can be uniformly approximated by $C^1$ functions with derivative bounded by $K$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/918610/every-k-lipschitz-function-can-be-uniformly-approximated-by-c1-functions-wi)), but is there a way to show what I want without using absolute continuity/mollifers?